# JSON vs SharedPreferences package

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to store some data, and use these as well, likes lists and numbers, which is the best method to do this?

So far I've found just these 2 ways: using a JSON or using the SharedPreferences package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store JSON files directly in flutter, it will be serialized and then stored. However, if you want to store complex data (not key/value pair) it would be difficult to store it in `SharedPreferences`. However since you have mentioned that you want to store lists, I would strongly advise you not to use `SharedPrefences` and use a more robust and flexible solutions. Check the official flutter [Cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence) for more info, but keep in mind that there exist other techniques that might work better in your case depending on the structure of the data and your state management solution. Example (Redux and Redux Persist).

Comment: my app is a music player so i just want to store the paths of the songs, in order to create playlists, and other small values such as volume or images path.
So as @dshukertjr said i should use ```sqflite```

Comment: In this case I would recommend you to use a database such as SQLite or others. The flutter cookbook discusses how to use SQLite [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store complex data, `sqflite` is there to save your day.

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

`sqflite` is essentially a local SQL database that you can store and query data. It's super fast and you can store it has more flexibility than `SharedPreferences`.